# Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time,

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

i am using java 1.6,Apache tomcat 7.0,Eclipse Luna. i just created dynamic web project and i have configured server and when i try to restart server it saying "Server Tomcat v 7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."

i increased start time,re-installed tomcat server,change work space in eclipse.i did above things but no use

and i tried what here mentioned but no use' [Tomcat Server not starting with in 45 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498724/tomcat-server-not-starting-with-in-45-seconds) '

Comment: Did you also remove the runtime environment when you removed and re-installed the server?

Comment: i did but no use.......

Comment: http://sansatechnology.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/how-to-fix-eclipse-tomcat-not-starting-in-45-seconds/

Comment: Does it work if you start the server from command line?

Comment: Check the eclipse log files under workspace/metadata/.log if there are any exceptions associated tothat problem. Seems to be a problem with the server configuration of the plugin.

Comment: It might also help if you mentioned your exact OS, Java and Tomcat versions...

Comment: thkala where i need to mention exact OS, Java and Tomcat versions

Answer (score -1):

Please amend the start time to the greater value as demonstrated in this screenshot

[[image: Screenshot showing the solution]]