# Tomcat 7.0 not starting withing 45 seconds even in a empty workspace

Tags: tomcat7

I have been using Tomcat 6.0 with jre 1.6 on eclipse for over more than 2 years now without any issue when i updated my jdk version to 1.7 and tomcat to 7.0.

Since then , i am continuously facing  "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds." error during server startup. I am using a windows 7 32 bit system .

Have tried deleting the server from eclipse , linking it again  , creating a new workspace ,  restarting eclipse but in vain. Have tried all the options from the below link but nothing works for me

[Tomcat Server not starting with in 45 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498724/tomcat-server-not-starting-with-in-45-seconds).

Please assist.

Comment: Try increasing the Timeout limit. Tomcat server>Timeouts> Start (in seconds)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo for the suggestion. However, the issue doesn't get resolved even with 120secs of timeout period .