# MacOS - Port 443 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, port, macos-sierra

I try to run a local tomcat7 server from my Eclipse on port 443.
But when I try to start it I get the following error:

> Port 443 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in
>   use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system
>   process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to
>   stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I looked around and saw a few answers to similar questions but can't get it to work.

I tried running Eclise as ROOT

```
$ sudo open /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

I also made sure that nothing is running on port 443

```
$ lsof -i :443
```

This returns nothing

When I go to 127.0.0.1:443 (http and https), I get the following result:

> This site can’t be reached
>   127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

my local tomcat (defined in Eclipse) server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <Connector port="443"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keyAlias="dev-tomcat-cert-es" 
               keystoreFile="<the correct path to the keystore file>" 
               keystorePass="<the correct password>"
               />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="ct-server" path="/app" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ct-server"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I am wondering if MacOs is running something on this port that I can't see.
Or if there is some kind of loop in my configuration which tries to connect twice to the port.

I am using MacOs-Sierra

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Regardless the port is bound or not, you cannot bind it unless you are root.

Comment: I am admin on this machine. What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Admin ist not root, you need uid 0. From within Eclipse, it is no necessary to run Tomcat with 443.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure of why it needs to run on port 443. It is how the project is configured, and I am new on it, just trying to run it at the moment. All the other developers are on Windows and have no issue. I will ask them for more info about this.

Comment: It does not have to run no 443. On Unix, any port below 1023 can only be bound by root, for security reasons. Windows does not care.

Answer (score 0):

Follow one single step:
1) Delete the server you have created.
  a)then create new server ofcourse (i hv attached screenshots for steps)

[Delete your current server][1]

For Creating new server:
1)create new server and delete previously added `Configure Environment Variable`

[Create new server (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC305.png)

[click on configure environment variables][3]

[remove the previously added variable and create new][4]

[while adding new click next and look for your installed jre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z45lr.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up if you installed tomcat on MacOs-Sierra using `brew`.
@Michael-O is right - you need to be root.

One good way to get round that is to bind to `8443` instead of `443`. Changing ports unleashes another error about the server [not starting within the set timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498724/tomcat-server-not-starting-with-in-45-seconds). 
Either that or the "[document does not exist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492454/eclipse-tomcat-error-document-base-does-not-exist-or-is-not-a-readable-director)" will hit first.
The hurdles aren't few. The easiest option - install tomcat using a zip file.

Go to https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi, download a zip, unzip it and in Eclipse, create a new server and specify "tomcat installation directory" as the unzipped file.